# Reveal the color of the image permanently once its hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need your expertise if this is possible, what im trying to do is coloring the image or reveal the image color part by part once the pen or your mouse hovered to it,  you can check the photo below

[image: the pen is user controlled]

My Current code is just reveal a gif once u click the portion of it, what im trying to do is i want to reveal the color of the image permanently once its hovered

```
<div class="intro-texts">
                <div id="div1">
                    <div class="auto-home-logo"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/logo-normal.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"></div>
                    <div class="blinking-home-text">    <span class="blink_text">Click to the cloud to enter</span> </div>
                </div>
                <div id="div2" class="fade-in">
                    <div class="auto-home-logo"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/hey2.gif" class="img-responsive center-block"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**JS**

```
var div1 = document.getElementById('div1'),
    div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
function switchVisible() {
  if(!div1) return;
  if (getComputedStyle(div1).display == 'block') {
    div1.style.display = 'none';
    div2.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    div1.style.display = 'block';
    div2.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
document.getElementById('div1').addEventListener('click', switchVisible);
```

Comment: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/185/how-to-get-the-pixel-color-from-a-canvas-on-click-or-mouse-event-with-javascript

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas

Comment: Lots of resources, searching for "get color of pixel javascript"

Answer (score -1):

You could try using the 'mouseover' event instead of 'click'.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Instead of posting multiple answers, either delete your old answer or modify it.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const div1 = document.querySelector('.div1');
const img = document.querySelector('.myImage');

div1.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
   img.classList.remove('myImage');
});
```

```css
.myImage {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); 
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
<img src="something.png" class="myImage">
</div>
```

Sorry if this is not close to what you're asking.

Comment: This also doesn't answer the question. The OP wants to color the pixels of image where the mouse passes over the image; not the entire image on hover.